# How to extend an object that has a private constructor?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, constructor

I have a `person` object that has a private constructor which is coming from an external service. In the constructor the `firstname` and `lastname` are taken off of the database. now for unit testing, I want to feed the `firstname` and `lastname` in order to not hit the database in unit test.

How can I extend my class and add a constructor extension that feeds the `firstname` and `lastname` in the unit test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a class *only* has a private constructor, you simply can't derive from it except as a nested type. Basically it sounds like the type you want to use is not amenable to being used in tests :(

When you say the type "is coming from an external service" - what do you mean, exactly? Do you mean the source code isn't under your control at all? Or is it *partially* under your control? For example, if this is generated code you could consider adding a build step to modify it...

Comment: 'Person' class is defined in an external package which is unchangable

Comment: @user3311522: In that case you just can't do it, I'm afraid. Does the type implement any kind of interface you could create an alternative implementation for?

Comment: If the `Person` class is from an external package, you should abstract it in your domain code.  (you don't want your domain to depend on the external package).  Then your unit tests only care about your abstraction of the `Person` class.

Answer (score 1):

1. Constructors aren't inherited, so you'd need to define a *new* constructor for your derived class.
2. Unit-testing via a derived class is not a great idea since you'd need to replicate any private implementation.

It sounds like your class is tightly coupled to some external data source - could you instead *inject* some sort of provider that you could mock in unit tests?

**EDIT**

Based on comments, it seems like this is a third-party library, in which case *it's not your responsibility to unit-test it*.  You should instead unit test YOUR code, and mock/stub the use of third-party libraries (which also means you should loosely-couple the use of the library through an interface of some sort).

Comment: Point 2 is not correct - if the constructor were `protected`, or if it were `internal` and in the same assembly (or one with visibility due to InternalsVisibleTo). Heck, even if it's private you can still derive from it within the source code of the same class (as a nested type).

Comment: @JonSkeet point taken - removed that since you cover it in your answer.